# Error while generating static page in SXA

Tags: sxa, error-handling

[image]
I am trying to generate a static error page for the website. I am getting this error while creating.

I have published the entire site.

I am using following blog/article for the same :-

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/generate-a-custom-static-error-page.html

Comment: Can you check if any error log is generating?

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore behind the scenes tries to access the error page, download page source and save it in `~/ErrorPages/<sitename>.html`. Looks like your error page couldn't be load. Try to access it from browser by manually pasting link to it.
If it doesn't show up then it's probably not published. Check if you don't have any publishing restrictions on that page.